# How to use boost serialization for binary output?

Tags: c++, boost

what is difference between functions boost::serialization::binary_object(void * t, size_t size)  and boost::serialization::make_binary_object(void * t, size_t size)?

How can i use them for getting actual output binary file ?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to SO!!

Here is an example showing how to use it.

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using boost::serialization::make_binary_object;

enum class Example : uint8_t {
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
};

int main() {

    std::stringstream stream;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(stream, boost::archive::no_header);

    auto data = Example::A;
    ar << make_binary_object(&data, sizeof(data));

    std::cout << "Size: " << stream.str().size() << "\n";
}
```

If you want to save the binary object in a file, here is an example that will save it in a file called data.dat

```
#include <fstream>

using boost::serialization::make_binary_object;

enum class Example : uint8_t {
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
};

int main() {

    std::ofstream f("data.dat", std::ofstream::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(f, boost::archive::no_header);

    auto data = Example::A;
    ar << make_binary_object(&data, sizeof(data));  
}
```

After running the code the file looks something like this
[image: data.dat file]

From the boost source code comments posted by @StoryTeller
make_binary_object() is just a little helper to support the convention that all serialization wrappers follow the naming convention make_xxxxx

Comment: I don,t get one thing , that how can i get get binary file saved under specific name using into folder .

Comment: Just use a file stream fstream you can find examples of that on the Internet. Please mark my answer as correct.. thanks!

Comment: I will add an example that writes a file.

Answer (score 2):

`boost::serialization::make_binary_object(void * t, size_t size)` is a helper and calls `boost::serialization::binary_object(void * t, size_t size)`. The helper is provided to preserve naming convention *make_xxxxx*

To save the object to a binary file you need to create an Archive and call `void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /* file_version */)` method of your `binary_object`