# How to serialize and unserialize a variable length struct in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to dump data into file and load it back with high performance later.

my idea is to design a variable length struct, using a member variable to mark the struct length.

long length represents this struct' size is big, short length represents this struct's size is small.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/time.h>

class DepthUpdate {
 public:
  size_t length_;
  timeval t_, ex_t_;
  char ticker_[16];
  char exchange_[16];
  double *bp_, *ap_;
  size_t *bv_, *av_;

  DepthUpdate(size_t len) : length_(len) {
    bp_ = new double[length_]; ap_ = new double[length_];
    bv_ = new size_t[length_]; av_ = new size_t[length_];
  }

  void Dump(std::fstream * f) {
    f->write((char*)this, sizeof(DepthUpdate) - sizeof(bp_) * 2 - sizeof(bv_) * 2); 
    f->write((char*)bp_, sizeof(double) * length_);
    f->write((char*)ap_, sizeof(double) * length_);
    f->write((char*)bv_, sizeof(size_t) * length_);
    f->write((char*)av_, sizeof(size_t) * length_);
  }

  static size_t calsize(size_t len) {
    return sizeof(DepthUpdate) - sizeof(bp_) * 2 - sizeof(bv_) * 2 + len * (sizeof(double) + sizeof(size_t)) * 2;
  }

  static std::pair<const DepthUpdate*, size_t> Load(void * ptr) {
    DepthUpdate* du = (DepthUpdate*)ptr;
    // std::cout << *(du->bp_) << std::endl;
    du->ap_ = du->bp_ + du->length_;
    du->bv_ = (size_t*)(du->ap_ + du->length_);
    du->av_ = du->bv_ + du->length_;
    printf("len = %zu\n", du->length_);
    return std::make_pair(du, calsize(du->length_));
  }
};
```

As above shows, in this struct, there is a member variable named `length_`, it decide the length of `bp_` and `ap_`;

and for dump, i will do like this:

```
std::fstream f("a.bin", std::ios::out);
DepthUpdate du(10);
du.Dump(f);
```

for load:

```
std::fstream f("a.bin", std::ios::in);
char buff[65536];
f.read(buff, sizeof(buff));
const auto & [p, offset] = DepthUpdate::Load(buff);
cout << p->bp_[0] << endl;
```

but i crashed when i visit du.bp_.

could you help on this? Is there any better methods can do this?

Comment: This is some severe type punning. I think a bunch of this may be undefined behaviour. `DepthUpdate* du = (DepthUpdate*)ptr;` You probably need to at least start with copying the data into your internal buffer.

Comment: You might want to use std::vector for things like `bp_` since a vector will keep track of its own size. When you read back just make sure not to cast a memory pointer to a C++ object but to explicitly create an object from the read data.

Comment: Whenever you have multiple self-managed arrays of the exact same length, consider a vector of structs instead. You're making your life unnecessarily hard. Also, using a buffer size with a power of two is called "Cargo Cult Programming". At least assign a constant and document its source accordingly!

Comment: Before you continue, study some more on the subject of binary serialization, it is not an easy thing to do right. There are many articles and probably some existing libraries you can use. (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54436690/how-to-use-boost-serialization-for-binary-output)

Comment: Personally I'd probably use [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) for something like this.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it's true, but i do care about file size, assume besides the variable length is 1000, if i use vector of struct, i will waste 1000's sizeof(other member variable)

Comment: I'm not sure where you think you're wasting space. My argument was like this: Assume you want to store (x,y) points. Using `vector<float> xs, ys;` would be better written `struct point{float x; float y}; vector<point> points;`. The key indicator that using separate vectors is wrong is when the sizes of two vectors are never different. Here, you don't have a lone x without a y, so they belong in the same vector. BTW: I'm saying `vector<>` here, because manual dynamic arrays using `new[]` are a bad idea in and of themselves.